# Deleting wchar_t* cause heap corruption

Tags: c++, mfc, heap-corruption

I've this portion of code:

```
class CNuovoVocabolo {
    CString m_strItaliano;
    CString m_strRusso;
    //...
}

void CNuovoVocabolo::GetVocabolo( CVocabolo* pVocabolo )
{
    int nLIta;
    int nLRus;
    wchar_t *pIta;
    wchar_t *pRus;

    nLIta = m_strItaliano.GetLength();
    nLRus = m_strRusso.GetLength();
    if( nLIta > 0 && nLRus > 0 )
    {
        pIta = new wchar_t[nLIta + 1];
        wcscpy_s( pIta, nLIta * sizeof( wchar_t ), m_strItaliano );
        pRus = new wchar_t[nLRus + 1];
        wcscpy_s( pRus, nLRus * sizeof( wchar_t ), m_strRusso );
        pVocabolo->SetVocabolo( pIta, nLIta, pRus, nLRus );
        delete [] pIta; // *1
        delete [] pRus; // *2
    }
}

// Inside CVocabolo::SetVocabolo:
void CVocabolo::SetVocabolo( const wchar_t* pIta/*=NULL*/, unsigned short nLIta/*=0*/, const wchar_t* pRus/*=NULL*/, unsigned short nLRus/*=0*/ )
{
    if( pIta != NULL && pRus != NULL && nLIta > 0 && nLRus > 0 )
    {
        AzzeraVocabolo();
        m_nLIta = nLIta;
        m_nLRus = nLRus;
        m_pItaliano = new wchar_t[nLIta + 1];
        wcscpy_s( m_pItaliano, nLIta * sizeof( wchar_t ), pIta );
        m_pRusso = new wchar_t[nLRus + 1];
        wcscpy_s( m_pRusso, nLRus * sizeof( wchar_t ), pRus );
    }
}
```

When I delete pIta pointer and pRus pointer at *1 and *2 I get a crash because of heap corruption. Honestly I can't understand why this is happening and where I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
Looking on the Net, I've found my solution:

```
pIta = new wchar_t[( nLIta + 1 ) * sizeof( wchar_t )];
```

But to be honest, it's unclear for me. If you can give me an explaination...
Also, knowing why the question got downvoted would be nice.

Comment: wcscpy_s looks very suspicious, especially the multiplication by sizeof (wchar_t).

Comment: A good start would be to stop using pointers and dynamic allocation on the heap, and start using `std::wstring`.

Comment: seconds argument of `wcs_cpy_s` is `numberOfElements`, not bytes. So no multiplication is needed.

Comment: @ivangrynko Not using * sizeof( wchar_t ) causes a Buffer too small exception.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here.

```
pIta = new wchar_t[nLIta + 1];
wcscpy_s( pIta, nLIta * sizeof( wchar_t ), m_strItaliano );
```

In the first line, the size is an array of wide characters plus a null terminator. This is correct.

In the second line, the size required is the number of characters plus null too, but you've given it a much larger number by the multiplication. This is wrong.

If these are `short` characters and a 20 character string, the first argument is 21 and the second is 40 (it should be 21 also). By itself this would be a silent mistake. Unfortunately for you, in the DEBUG build (which I assume you are using) the wcscpy_s function fills the entire buffer, neatly overwriting unallocated memory.

The reason your fix works is that you (wrongly) made the buffer big enough to hold the (wrong) length copy, and two wongs made a white (oops!).

Fix 1: remove the multiplication by sizeof and add 1 for the null.

Fix 2: stop using these horrible functions and start writing some good C++ using wstring etc.

Edit: allow for null on destination. (oops)

Comment: It's also funny how the "secure" variants of these functions cause a buffer overflow.

Comment: Well, I've tried to remove the * sizeof( wchar_t ) in wcscpy_s but this causes "buffer too small" error. How should I fix this error then?

Comment: Sorry, you need to allow for the null (see edit). But you could easily have found that the same way I did, by checking the MSDN documentation.

Comment: @rubenvb: If you check the MS docs, these are _not_ the current secure variants. MS provides templated secure variants which avoid these problems.

Comment: @david.pfx if I'm not mistaken, the C11 Annex K secure CRT functions were modelled after the MS implementation (which was the only one at the time of standardization). I may be wrong though...

Comment: @rubenvb: I think you're right. MS certainly put a lot of effort into fixing their code base to use techniques like this, and pushing it out into dev land. However, this Q has a C++ tag and with C++ templates you can avoid obvious mistakes like getting the wrong sizeof.